# has anyone tried designing a webpage for psp?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, playstation-portable

I'm trying to make a personal bible for my psp

(I tried googling but the only bible version I've seen on my skimming is on KJV and I'm trying to make mine have 3 versions namely TNIV, NLT and Amplified Bible)

So my only solution was to make on for myself and my approach was to save an html file on my mem-stick and open it up through the console's browser

My concerns are:

1. How does the psp browser handle css and javascript?
2. Is there a doctype declaration specifically designed for the psp browser?
3. Can I use any local database to store my texts for easier query or do I have no choice but rely on static text files?
4. Is there anyone in SO who have experienced developing a page for this console and can he/she give me some tips and advice?

Thanks much in advance for your responses. :)

Comment: Hi lock! Just wanted to suggest putting more effort in formatting and spelling in your posts. The more effort you put in writing your posts, the more effort you can expect from people writing answers. Just a hint...

Answer (score 1):

1. The PSP has good (but not great) CSS support and weak Javascript support (compared to a desktop browser).
2. The best Doctype to stick to would be XHTML Strict 1.0.
3. Not unless you find another way to do it.
4. Not for the PSP, but I would recommend this: Just keep your markup and CSS as simple as possible. Don't set font-sizes or widths, let the PSP browser do that for you. If you need to generate a bunch of static files, it might be worth building a short script that will do it for you. Don't overcomplicate.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i guess this time i wont have to rely on jquery :)

Answer (score 1):

Well the best way would be to make an HTML document file to create an off-line web page.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my concern #1, I found only this as reference for all script objects that the psp browser supports as of their latest release.. I'm not sure if SCE would add more support for other objects in the future though

Anyhow [here's the link](http://slayeroffice.com/articles/psp/)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your issue (not your question), have you thought about using http://www.biblegateway.com/ which can show verses in different Bible translations - instead of writing your code to try to do the same thing?
Granted, this only works if you are connected to the Internet.